# How to change date from DD.MM.YYYY to YYYY.MM.DD in EXCEL?

Tags: excel, sorting, date, date-format

Pls help me with this!
I have a sheet with some columns (some products), one of the colums is with expire date of products and the format of column is "20/3/2017 (DD.MM.YY)". I want to sort entire sheet by this column but i can't because excel make short after first number "DD". 
I tried with format cells, and changed format day on custom field with "YYYY.MM.DD", but nothing happened. :(
I tried with text to columns, but some dates are changing, others won't and i don't understand why is not changing all...
I tried to export my data with computer date changed to English(South Africa) because the format date there is YYYY.MM.DD but nothing happened.
Is there a formula to help me? I tried all ideas on google, but nothing....

Comment: If you provide a sample file, it'll be easier to see what is the problem.

Comment: Have you tried using text to columns with `/` as the delimiter? Then you could concatenate the columns back together in the order you'd like. What I think is happening is you're changing the format of the cells, but excel doesn't actually update the underlying data until you click into the cell. You can test this by doing text to columns using a delimiter not present in the column (`|` for example). This will force exel to update the underlying data formats to whatever you choose when running that function.

Answer (score 1):

[Print Screen of my column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIvCk.jpg)

an example...

Comment: Do text to columns on that column with `|` as the delimiter and text as the data type. Then post an updated screenshot.